# Where put an serialized file object on project netbeans

Tags: serialization, servlets, netbeans

I've an desktop application that implements Serializable class, but now I'm translating it to an web app with servlets, I use Netbeans for this work,I have the following code:

```
InputStream input = ClassLoader.getSystemResourceAsStream(file_input);
```

Where file_input is an bytecode fyle from an object serialized before, I don't know where I should put this file because in the desktop application I put it in the same dir where I had my classes.

(I have the file, I don't need to create it).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `ClassLoader#getSystemResourceAsStream()` in a Java EE web application, ever. Instead, use `ClassLoader#getResourceAsStream()`. I would also put big question marks around using `ClassLoader#getSystemResourceAsStream()` in a Java SE desktop application, for sure if it's intended to be distributable, but that aside.

The `ClassLoader` ultimately loads resources from the classpath. So all you need to do is to make sure that the file is placed in one of the paths which are by default covered by the webapp's runtime classpath, *or* to add the new path to the file to the webapp's runtime classpath through a server specific configuration setting, such as `shared.loader` property of Tomcat's `/conf/catalina.properties`.

One of the default paths covered by the webapp's runtime classpath is the `/WEB-INF/classes` folder of the WAR. From IDE project's perspective, just drop the file in the root folder of the "Java Source" (src) folder, there where you have all your Java packages and classes. The IDE will take care that it ultimately ends up in `/WEB-INF/classes` of the built WAR file.

I by the way still assume that you are *not* creating the file from inside the webapp, as you explicitly told. That wouldn't work. If you *actually* need to have write access as well, you're going to need an absolute disk file system path instead. You can always make it configureable by providing it as a VM argument or environment variable, for example.